# How can I use php-FFMpeg in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am new to Laravel 4. I have installed `php-ffmpeg` in my local Laravel setup, but I need help on how to use this ffmpeg with Laravel 4?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Pls say me how can i use if u know about that.

Comment: Now solved this question myself.  I found the command for that and also give path with command. Thanks

Comment: than it would be nice if you add solution as answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have `ffmpeg` installed on your localhost server, then in Laravel, you need to set the paths for the **ffmpeg** and **ffprobe** binaries, like so:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
         'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.1.3/bin/ffmpeg', 
         'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.1.3/bin/ffprobe', 
         'timeout'          => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
         'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,   // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
));
```

By doing so, then you can:

```
// set the path of the video file, which you might consider to get the input from the user 
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');

// apply filters to resize the clip 
$video
  ->filters()
  ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
  ->synchronize();

// crop a frame from a particular timecode
$video
  ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
  ->save('frame.jpg');

// transcode clip
$video
  ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4');
```

There are more examples provided in the PHP-FFMpeg documentation on [github](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)