# How to make ffmpeg run from laravel cron

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, cron, centos

I have a laravel command that generates summary jpeg file (contact sheet) from a video file, using `exec('ffmpeg ...')`.

When I call it from command-line (like this: `php artisan file:generate` or `su - nginx -s /bin/sh -c 'php artisan file:generate'`) it works, but if I have it in the crontab, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: See this page [how-can-i-use-php-ffmpeg-in-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838135/how-can-i-use-php-ffmpeg-in-laravel-4)

Comment: How did you set the cronjob? Check `www-data` permissions and try setting the cron with `crontab -u www-data -e`